# Javascript not generated from Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, aurelia

I am creating an Aurelia application using Visual Studio 2015 and Typescript.  I am using ASP.Net Core 1.0 R2.

Before yesterday when I compiled my application the .js files were generated and showed up just after the .ts files (see image).

[image]

I did something yesterday where they stopped being generated and I have no idea what I did.  I am learning Typescript so not familiar enough with this to begin to know where to look.  The only results I got searching the internet told me that the .js files were created in an appBundle.js file but I think this is old information because that was not the behavior I was seeing before yesterday, and my Aurelia app is not running because it says it cannot find the .js files.

Can anyone shed some light on what I need to do to get the .js files to be generated again?

**UPDATE:**

I deleted the app.html and app.ts files and recreated them and then rebuilt the project and suddenly the .js files are showing up and my app runs fine now.

[image]

Not sure why this fixed the problem, might be bug.

Anybody have any insight?

Comment: Could you share your `tsconfig.json` and is VS reporting any TypeScript errors on save or build?

Comment: We would need to see the project folder structure and the corresponding `tsconfig.json`

Comment: I could imagin that you had an error in your app.ts and the typescript compiler was stopping because of that. This behaviour depends on your settings to the typescript compiler/tsconfig

Comment: @kabaehr Your answer is the correct one.  If you want to write it up as an answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Added an answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the typescript controller is not compiling your `.ts` files anymore because you have an error in your `app.ts` file.

This behaviour depends on your settings to the typescript compiler (tsconfig file)

Comment: It was the `noEmitOnError` option.  It was set to `true` and I had errors so the javascript files were being not be generated.  Changing it to `false` resolved my problem (although fixing the compiler errors would also fix it :))